In the Expo React Native application, only the splash screen appears
I've just started mobile development with React Native. For some reason I don't understand, after turning off the computer and turning it on, the application does not give any error message, but the splash screen does not disappear from the screen. The login page or home page does not appear. What is the problem or is there somewhere I can look at the logs?


did you restart the emulator as well? try building app again

yup i did but thats not did fixed my problem.I even cleared the cache

There can be network issue on android simulator. If you have changed laptop/pc wifi then you have to restart the emulator for running on to that same wifi.

I use the same computer and the same wifi. I didn't change anything.
